# Firebase как отравить пуш напрямую без помощи PHP

Tags: android, firebase

Написал чат на firebase , теперь нужно решить отправку   пуш уведомлений , ранее использовал связку  php/mysql, но  тут более интенсивная информация , посоветуйте как можно напрямую через firebase отправить push

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: это не то ,мне нужно с одного устройство на другое на прямую

Comment: Вам нужно знать его токен что бы отправить на конкретное устройство.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пуши можно отправлять рест клиентом, а значит можно реализовать POST запрос и с андроид устройства.

урл

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

заголовки

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=...
```

ключ - Server key (legacy token) (берется из консоли firebase)

примерный body:

```
{
    "from":"...",
    "to":"...",
    "data": {
        "text": "Hello"
     },
     "time_to_live": 108
}
```

from - sender id, тоже из консоли firebase

to - токен получателя

В ресивере нужно будет обработать - вытащить text из remoteMessage.getData() и реализовать свою логику

Comment: Спасибо большое за четкий ответ!